# Python to sqlite3: Insert elements from a list as new rows in a databse

Tags: python, list, sqlite, loops

I am using Stanford's SNAP RateBeer data set which contains user reviews for specific beers across 13 fields. I loaded the data from a compressed text file and now have the data sitting in a list. I am trying to insert this data into a sqlite3 database so that each row is auser review for a particular beer.

Two methods that I thought could work:

- Every 14 fields, add a new entry (13 fields and a blank)
- Every time there is a blank entry in the list, insert a new row

Any thoughts would be much appreciated -- thanks!

An example row with relevant information is below:

```
['beer/name: John Harvards Simcoe IPA\n', 
 'beer/beerId: 63836\n',
 'beer/brewerId: 8481\n',
 'beer/ABV: 5.4\n',
 'beer/style: India Pale Ale &#40;IPA&#41;\n',
 'review/appearance: 4/5\n',
 'review/aroma: 6/10\n',
 'review/palate: 3/5\n',
 'review/taste: 6/10\n',
 'review/overall: 13/20\n',
 'review/time: 1157587200\n',
 'review/profileName: hopdog\n',
 'review/text: On tap at the Springfield, PA location. Poured a deep and cloudy orange (almost a copper) color with a small sized off white head. Aromas or oranges and all around citric. Tastes of oranges, light caramel and a very light grapefruit finish. I too would not believe the 80+ IBUs - I found this one to have a very light bitterness with a medium sweetness to it. Light lacing left on the glass.\n',<br>
 '\n'] # Empty field
```

Comment: Is your data in a list of lists, or just one big list? If the latter, can you show your code to load the list?

Comment: @mechanical_meat thanks for your response. It's one large list of ~41M elements. The code is: beer_list = []

`beer_list = []

with gzip.open('SNAP-Ratebeer.txt.gz', 'rt') as f:
     for line in f:
        beer_list.append(line)`

Comment: You're welcome. And thanks for the explanation of your data structure. I'm thinking that if you're assured that there are the same number of rows for each beer you could take chunks of the list and further process those chunks. If you're not assured there are the same number of rows for each beer then this becomes more difficult.